# Is the use of a volatile dictionary a good option when high speed network messaging is involved?

Tags: c#, networking, thread-safety, volatile

**Premise**

I am working on a multiplayer game and I have a number of network controlled actors, the inputs of witch I decided to store in a volatile dictionary:

```
public static volatile Dictionary<string, QuickMessage> quickPlayerMessages;
```

And each frame the actors fetch their values from that dictionary, but independently of that I also have a receiver thread that constantly updates that dictionary, so the values constantly get changed and keys may be deleted or added to it. I did a few tests and this works but...

**My concerns**

I do not fully understand the volatile modifier, I know that it is supposed to eliminate some optimizations that may result in the reading of a partially written information. I also heard that this isn't really functioning like if you did it with a lock mechanism. While I did pick this solution because it cut down a lot of complexity for me and it looks like it is fairly responsive(speedwise) I do have this feeling of unease about it.

Is there any issue that may arise or that I should be aware of from this approach?

Comment: Why you don't use a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, QuickMessage>`?

Comment: Unless you are assigning new instances to `quickPlayerMessages` (i.e. `quickPlayerMessages = ....`) I would say `volatile` should be irrelevant here.

Comment: @TimSchmelter good question, the thing with the concurent dictonary is that it has that concurency level and that dissuaded me from using it...

Comment: As for using `Dictionary` in with multiple threads - as docs [state](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#thread-safety): _A Dictionary<TKey,TValue> can support multiple readers concurrently, as long as the collection is not modified. Even so, enumerating through a collection is intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure. In the rare case where an enumeration contends with write accesses, the collection must be locked during the entire enumeration._

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`volatile` is probably not the correct approach for this. What volatile does is forcing the value to be read from memory rather than from cache. Reading or writing a reference, or a value smaller than a IntPtr is atomic in c#. But without some kind of memory barrier the value could be cached, and changes on one thread might not be visible for other threads. Volatile inserts some memory barriers to solve some of the visibility issues.

In this scenario you do not seem to replace the dictionary, so `volatile` would do nothing. You are however mentioning you are updating the dictionary. This is not threadsafe without a lock. But you might however consider a [`ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2?view=net-5.0) instead. A concurrent dictionary would however only guarantee that the dictionary itself is thread safe, you will still need to consider the overall thread safety of your program.

Also, your primary concern should be that the program is correct, speed is secondary.

Comment: So the objects inside it are not volatile themselves?(Or at least located in a volatile zone of memory)

Comment: @TobyB no. volatile is not a magic make thread safe keyword. It solves one particular, very narrow problem. And it is arguably better to use Interlocked.Exchange/Read even then. If in doubt you should use a *lock*. Locks have its own issues and dangers but it solves many of the possible concurrency problems. Writing multithreaded code is not the place to use trial and error, it is way to easy to write code fails 0.001% of the time and is impossible to debug. You need some understanding of the hazards.

Comment: I see I will siwtch then to a concurent Dictonary like sugested, this has been eyeopening, thank you.